# PHP stdClass Object with dot

Tags: php, stdclass

I have a stdClass, that has an attribute with a dot in it's name. It's returned to me via an API, so there's nothing I can do with the name.
It looks like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [GetPlayerResult] => stdClass Object ( [RegistrationResponses.Player] => Array (...)
```

Now, how do I access the array? When I do this:

```
print_r($result->GetPlayerResult->RegistrationResponses.Player);
```

it (obviously) prints just "Player". I have tried putting apostrophes around the last part, using [''] syntax (like an associative array), none of that works and throws a 500 error.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using braces:

```
$object->GetPlayerResult->{"RegistrationResponses.Player"}
```

Or you can cast it to an associative array

```
$result = (array) $object->GetPlayerResult;
$player = $result["RegistrationResponses.Player"];
```

If you are parsing your website response using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-parameters), note the existence of the second parameter to return as associative array:

> #### **assoc**
>
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Answer (score -2):

Please convert your object to array by using this function

```
$arr = (array) $obj;
echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);exit;
```

by print $arr you can  show elements of array.

Comment: You can't _access_ an element of an array using print_r... You only see it from the output, but not actually "access" it by reading it into a useful value. And I don't think printing an associative array has any obvious advantages over printing an object... Moreover, you are only casting the shallow object into an array, but the deep objects are still objects.

Comment: ok i just want to convey that you can see all the elements nothing else.

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing without converting it to an array. Especially when you don't really deeply convert it into an array.